# json_decode variables to email

Tags: json, api, paypal-ipn, php-7, bitpay

I am using btcpayserver with bitpay php api. Trying to implement ipn in payments and send variables to email.

the ipn generates a log file like this:

```
Raw IPN: {
  "id": "KrYtvetS9oQ9s7CDErk,
  "url": "https://btcpayserv.net/invoice?id=KrYtvetS9oQ9s7",
  "posData": null,
  "status": "paid",
  "btcPrice": "0.00162327",
  "price": 11.99,
  "currency": "EUR",
  "invoiceTime": 1569570609000,
  "expirationTime": 1569571509000,
  "currentTime": 1569570697070,
  "btcPaid": "0.00162327",
  "btcDue": "0.00000000",
  "rate": 7386.36657706093,
  "exceptionStatus": false,
  "buyerFields": {
    "buyerEmail": "buyeremail@test.com"
  },
  "transactionCurrency":
```

the ipn get data like this in php: $ipn = json_decode($raw_post_data);

php

```
$ipn = json_decode($raw_post_data);

$invoice = $client->getInvoice($ipn->id);
$invoiceId = $invoice->getId();
$invoiceUrl = $invoice->getUrl();
$invoiceStatus = $invoice->getStatus();
$invoiceExceptionStatus = $invoice->getExceptionStatus();
$invoicePrice = $invoice->getPrice();
$invoiceBtcPrice = $invoice->getbtcPrice();
```

i could send some fields like this via php mail:

```
$message = 'Date:' . $date .  ', ID: ' . $invoiceId . ', Status: ' . $invoiceStatus . ', Url: ' . $invoiceUrl . ', BTC Price: ' . $invoiceBtcPrice . ', Price: ' . $invoicePrice;
```

but i will like to send this variable of the RAW IPN:  "buyerEmail": "buyeremail@test.com"

can not make it.